# how to get data from pragma background service in flutter

Tags: flutter

Today I am facing a strange problem with my flutter project. I define a ListQueue like this:

```
final ListQueue<Music> fmPlayQueue = ListQueue<Music>();
```

In the UI I am get the ListQueue size like this:

```
                AppBar(
                  title: Text("FM(${fmPlayQueue.length})"),
                  elevation: 0,
                  backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                ),
```

in the background service I run a schedule task to fill element into the queue:

```
 if (!isLegacyMusic) {
        print("songs title:" + recommend[i].title + ",legacy:" + isLegacyMusic.toString() + ",song id:" + recommend[i].id.toString());
        resultMusic.add(recommend[i]);
        if(!fmPlayQueue.contains(recommend[i])) {
          fmPlayQueue.add(recommend[i]);
        }
      }
```

I want to show the ListQueue size in UI,because the background service have a independent environment, I could not get value from background service directly. how to send the value from pragma background service into the UI? BTW, this is how to run my background service:

```
@pragma('vm:entry-point')
void playerBackgroundService() {
  CommonUtils.initialApp(ConfigType.PRO).whenComplete(() => {
    loadRepository()
  });
}

void loadRepository() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  GlobalConfig.init(ConfigType.PRO);
  neteaseRepository = NeteaseRepository();
  Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 10), (Timer t) => neteaseRepository!.appendMusic());
  runBackgroundService(
    imageLoadInterceptor: BackgroundInterceptors.loadImageInterceptor,
    playUriInterceptor: BackgroundInterceptors.playUriInterceptor,
    playQueueInterceptor: QuietPlayQueueInterceptor(),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Communicate from different engine is needed in this situation. Currently I solve this problem by start a http service in the engine like this:

```
void serviceStart() async {
  HttpServer.bind(InternetAddress.anyIPv4, 4049, shared: true).then((service) {
    print("service  ${service.address}  ${service.port}");
    service.listen((request) async {
      print(request.uri);
      switch (request.method) {
        case "POST":
          var result = await request
              .cast<List<int>>()
              .transform(utf8.decoder)
              .join()
              .then(json.decode);
          print("POST   $request");
          request.response
            ..headers.contentType = ContentType.json
            ..write(json.encode({
              "id": "sssss",
              "title": "response  hello  post",
            }))
            ..close();
          break;
        case "GET":
          request.response
            ..headers.contentType = ContentType.json
            ..write(json.encode({
              "id": "idxxxxxx",
              "title": "GET  response ",
              "count":NeteaseGlobalConfig.fmPlayQueue.length
            }))
            ..close();
          break;
      }
    });
  });
}
```

then get the variable by send a http request.